# How to call php variable input text from another Php page

Tags: php, variables, input, session-variables

My question is how do I call input value of user selected which has show by php code from another php.

Normal simple way we get the input this way

```
 $calendar_id_val = $_GET['calendar_id'];
```

and now it is not working:

For example Show.php, I have one form which show the values from Database and show the result with php variable with While Loop.

```
<input name="calendar_id" value="<?php echo $calendar_id;?>">
```

and when user is submit that form I will carry these user selected value and perform insert.php

Comment: What is the type of your form.get or post..??Can you show the html..??

Comment: your form looks like this <form action="insert.php" method="get"> or <form action="insert.php" method="post"> ? if get is used in your form then you should use $_GET in insert page, if you used the post in your form then yous should use the $_POST variables in insert.php

Answer (score 0):

While you are doing echo in the input use echo $calendar_id_val

Comment: I call $calendar_id_val at second php "insert.php" and the result is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `form` like,

```
<form action="insert.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="calendar_id" value="<?php echo $calendar_id;?>"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_id" value="Insert"/>
</form>
```

**Insert.php**

```
echo $calendar_id_val = $_GET['calendar_id'];
```

Comment: my form function is using <form action="insert.php" method="get"> and I type same way as echo $calendar_id_val = $_GET['calendar_id']; 
the result is not shown

Comment: Try `print_r($_REQUSET)`, before echoing, also check whether or not it goes on `insert.php`

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
<form action="insert.php" method="GET">
    <input name="calendar_id" value="<?php echo $calendar_id;?>">
</form>
```

If you want to redirect the user back to `show.php`, add this to the end of your `insert.php` script

```
header('Location: show.php');
exit();
```

Comment: I know how to redirect back,it is not my question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `$_POST` var like this:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="calendar_id" value="<?php echo $calendar_id;?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

insert.php file:

```
echo $calendar_id = $_POST['calendar_id'];
```